# A kind of github ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, svn

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 with Subversion and I want to know if there's a tool that allows to see a project's change history. I'd like something like [GitHub](http://github.com), with a timeline chart that shows the changes done in choosen date.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Why does it have to be a rubygem?

Comment: While thinking about it, it doesn't need to be a rubygem.

Comment: I would like to know why are you mentioning RoR. Do you want to use that tool into your Rails project?

Comment: Have you considered a hosted subversion service that might provide this? http://beanstalkapp.com/ and http://www.springloops.com/v2/ are two that come to mind.

Answer (score -1):

[Gitlab](http://gitlabhq.com/) might be what you are looking for.
But it only works for Git. You can port your project to Git though, and use *git-svn*.

Comment: I took a look to gitlab and is great for me, but I'm not quiet about -1, could the rater explain me why?

Comment: I believe I got a *-1* because I talked about a Git tool while you were asking for a Subversion one.